# what is MD5 fingerprint and what is it usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think i'm missing a very obvious thing. I knew in rails that

> Rails inserts an MD5 fingerprint into each filename so that the file
>   is cached by the web browser.

I tried to find what is the MD5 fingerprint , all what I found was about finding or generating it , no one explained what exactly is it...
so ,
 **what exactly is MD5 fingerprint ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MD5 is a cryptographic function. It turns data (in your example the contents of files) into a short string. Its beauty is that if the data changes just a tiny bit, the MD5 will be different as well.

Therefore, MD5 is a good way to make a "fingerprint" so that you can compare files very quickly to know if they have changed. In your example if the file has changed just a tiny bit, Rails will put a brand new MD5 string in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

It is an hash cryptographic function that produce a 128 bit digest, that is the output of the function. A characteristic of that kind of function is that they are one way functions, so it is very difficult to find the original value who produced a given hash. Another fundamental characteristic is that it is very difficult, given a value with an hash, to find another value that produces the same hash.